# forEach method not setting style property for list items

Tags: javascript, foreach, undefined, htmlcollection

Here is app.js

```
const listItems=document.querySelector(".student-list").children;
const numberOfItems=10;
const page=document.querySelector(".page");

displayPage=(list,pageNumber)=> {
   const SI=(pageNumber*numberOfItems)-numberOfItems
   const EI=pageNumber*numberOfItems
   Array.of(list).forEach((item,index)=> {
      if (index>= SI && index<EI) {
         item.style.display="block";
      } else {
         item.style.display="none";
      }
   })
}

addPaginationLinks=(list)=> {
   const pages=list.length/10
   let html=``
   for (let i=0; i<pages; i++) {
      html+=`
      <li>
         <a class="active" href="#">${i+1}</a>
      </li>`
      return html
   }
   ul=document.createElement("UL");
   ul.innerHTML=html;
   div=document.createElement("DIV");
   div.className.add("pagination");
   div.appendChild(ul);
   page.appendChild(div);
}




displayPage(listItems, 1);
addPaginationLinks(listItems);
```

Here is a sample of index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Students</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/design.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="page-header cf">
        <h2>Students</h2>
        <!-- dynamically insert search form here (optional) -->

      </div>
      <ul class="student-list">
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/67.jpg">
                <h3>iboya vat</h3>
                <span class="email">iboya.vat@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/15/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

There's no error in the html, it just continues down with more and more li's, and then closes up with a ul and a closing div tag. Then the script app js appears later.

I'm getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined Array.forEach

Basically, it's not recognizing each item in the list in the for each loop. Why is that? When I console log the items, the HTML collection shows up.

Comment: Yeah but I'm targetting each item in that list, so wouldn't it be item instead? Because the parameter item is representing each iteration, which is the li element.

Comment: Array.of creates a new array with parameters passed to it as elements. Array.of(list).forEach((item,index)=> { item.style.display="block" }) is the same as list.style.display = "block"

Comment: You need to use `Array.from` instead of `Array.of`

Comment: @Barmar okay array.from seemed to console log each element properly. Why is that lol? I didn't realize the distinction till now.

Comment: `Array.of(x, y, z)` is the same as `[x, y, z]`. `Array.from(x)` is the same as `[x[0], x[1], x[2], ...]`

Comment: @Barmar okay thank you. Also, in the addPagination function, the elements are not showing up on the at all. I console logged the pages variable and that works, but I can't console.log the html or any of the variables I created after the for loop. Could you also tell what's wrong there, if you don't mind?

Comment: Because of `return html` in the loop. That ends the function and it never executes the code after the loop.

Comment: `div.className.add` should be `div.classList.add`